# How to Reference Yodlee SOAP API

Tags: api, soap, yodlee

I'm attempting to utilize the Yodlee SOAP API for a web application in ASP.NET 4.5.  I was under the impression that I could add a service reference to it with the url:

https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/v1.0

However, this did not work and gave me the following error message:

There was an error downloading 'https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/v1.0/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.

### The request failed with the error message:

The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /services/services/v1.0/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata
--.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/v1.0'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/v1.0'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Am I attempting to reference the Yodlee SOAP API incorrectly?  We used to aggregate financial investment data with Yodlee a little over a year ago and have an old DLL utilizing the SOAP architecture which no longer works.  However, Yodlee no longer lists a DLL for ASP.NET with SOAP architecture.  We were hoping to utilize a majority of our old API method calls and this is why we'd like to utilize SOAP for the time being, otherwise we'd switch to REST.

If someone could please help, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The URL for making SOAP calls is

https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/

If you want to see the list of services, you can list it with the listServices appended to the URL as below

https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/listServices

The URL https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/ is for making REST calls and talk to Yodlee.

Please refer to the documentation at developer.yodlee.com for more information.

Hope this answers your question.

--Vijay

Comment: Any mex style endpoint - surely we can generate our client from an exposed endpoint somehow?