# Yodlee SOAP generating a java.lang.NullPointerException excetpion

Tags: c#, soap, yodlee

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19600181/5188)

I'm trying to run the [C# SOAP Sample App](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Sample_Apps/C%23_Sample_Apps) but getting the exception:
 **java.lang.NullPointerException**

I believe I'm using the wrong SOAP Endpoint.

From [the Sample App](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Sample_Apps/C%23_Sample_Apps), the endpoint for CobrandLogin is created via:

```
cobrandLoginService.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("soapServer") + "/" + cobrandLoginService.GetType().FullName+"_" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("soapServerVersion");
```

[The Dev Portal](https://devnow.yodlee.com/) shows *soapServer* should be:  https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services
[image: Yodlee Dev Portal]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761415/5188) suggests all sorts of random URLs that don't match the format:

> soapServer + service full name + _version

These don't match to [the Sample App](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Sample_Apps/C%23_Sample_Apps).  See here: https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/listServices

The sample app also asks for *tncVersion* and *soapServerVersion* although it isn't obvious what these settings should be.

Suggestions?  What is the correct URL cobrandLoginService and the other services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valuable feed back and we will have this documented in a better way. For now here is the answer to your question -

soapServer  - https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services

ServiceName - CobrandLoginService

soapServerVersion - 2013Q3(this is the current version we are recommending)

Hence the complete SOAP service EPR for cobrandLogin would look like -  https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/CobrandLoginService_2013Q3

Similarly you can create all the other EPRs with the help of [SOAP API reference guide](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference)
and verifying them from [listServices](https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/listServices)

WSDLs for this version can be found [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Sample_Apps/Wsdls)

```
The sample app also asks for tncVersion
```

tncVersion should be passed as 2